# After exporting jar console doesn't show up

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, console, export

I have written a small program in Java in Eclipse, which outputs something in the console using `System.out.println()` and asks for input. When I export it, and run it, the command line doesn't show up though. It does do something, and when I run it via `java -jar [filename]` it does show the output in the command prompt. I know it does something because I work with an Access-database, and after opening a connection between the database and Java, there is created a `.laccdb` file, so something does happen. I don't see anything though.

I hope it is clear what I mean and I also hope someone can help me!

Comment: _"When I export it, and run it"_ -- how do you run it? Double-click on the icon in Windows?

Comment: I don't understand, you said that when you run it via java -jar it does show it. What is the problem then? That it doesn't show up when you double-click it... it is not supposed to do it!

Comment: @JimGarrison I have ran it in two ways: 1. Via command line with `java -jar [filename]` 2. By double-clicking
First option works, second does doe something, but does not show the output.

Comment: @luanjot But I do output things in the command line, via `System.out.println()`. Shouldn't it show these outputs when running it with double-clicking?

Comment: If your program outputs to stdout and then terminates, the command line window may not have displayed for long enough to be visible.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. If you want, you can use a logging system and dump that log into a file.

Comment: @JimGarrison I thought so the same, that is why I tested it with an infinite loop, nothing showed up though...

Comment: @luanjot I think I'll just create a GUI then... Only thing to do is learning about action listeners... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ikhebgeenaccount OK. You can use an example that creates a Jframe and print there: http://www.comweb.nl/java/Console/Console.html

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, when double-clicking on a .jar-file that only outputs in the command line will not show the command line. The only way to accomplish this is by running the jar with `java -jar [filename]`.